# How to check options for scapy functions

Tags: python, scapy

Currently doing some python programming and I've come across a problem I can't find an answer for. Could be bad Googling... anyhow, I have things such as this

```
#  Construct the DNS packet
        DNSpkt = DNS(
            id=pkt[DNS].id, # use same id from captured packet
            qd=pkt[DNS].qd, # copy the question section from packet
            aa=1,       # Set flag for authoritative message
            qr=1,       # Set flag for reply message
            qdcount=1,      # one question  
            ancount=1,  # one answer
            an=Anssec)  # my bogus answer is set in reply
```

I would like to know how I can view the options a function like DNS takes. There's other ones as well,

```
IPpkt =  IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)
UDPpkt   =  UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport, sport=53)
```

For example, IP has dst and src as an option. I'd like to know how I would know that if all I saw was IP(). I'd like to know what the options take as well. For example, dst takes an ipv4 address. Please correct me on any terms I'm using as I believe that's the reason I can't find an answer for my question. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- from the reference doc: e.g. IP: https://scapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/scapy.layers.inet.html#scapy.layers.inet.IP This has a lot of infos.
- from the console: download scapy and use `./run_scapy` then do `ls(IP)`

> ```
> >>> ls(IP)
> version    : BitField  (4 bits)                  = (4)
> ihl        : BitField  (4 bits)                  = (None)
> tos        : XByteField                          = (0)
> len        : ShortField                          = (None)
> id         : ShortField                          = (1)
> flags      : FlagsField  (3 bits)                = (<Flag 0 ()>)
> frag       : BitField  (13 bits)                 = (0)
> ttl        : ByteField                           = (64)
> proto      : ByteEnumField                       = (0)
> chksum     : XShortField                         = (None)
> src        : SourceIPField                       = (None)
> dst        : DestIPField                         = (None)
> options    : PacketListField                     = ([])
> ```

- In addition you can use `rfc(IP)`, but note that this is already displayed on the online doc, and is purely informative as all names are capitalized.

> ```
> >>> rfc(IP)
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |VERSION|  IHL  |      TOS      |              LEN              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |               ID              |FLAGS|           FRAG          |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |      TTL      |     PROTO     |             CHKSUM            |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                              SRC                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                              DST                              |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |            OPTIONS            |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                              Fig. IP
> ```

Comment: It's under API reference.. nice.. I feel stupid. Thank you for that! As far as the ./run_scapy, ls(IP), and rfc(IP), I'm not sure how to go about executing those. I need the ELI5 (explain like I'm 5) explanation. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you need-

```py
In [33]: DNSpkt.fields
Out[33]: {'aa': 1, 'an': 'Anssec', 'ancount': 1, 'qdcount': 1, 'qr': 1}
```

(pkt is missing cause i haven't used it to instantiate DNS() object)

Comment: Where did you input that? Thanks for the comment. That's what I'm looking for although not quite it. I was able to find the source code I was looking for which answered many questions.

Comment: Just in my Ipython terminal. Created the DNS(...) object and then this. Python has good set of investigation tools, like `dir()` and attributes like` __doc__`, I usually find what I am looking for using these and also the ipython autocomplete option.